# Integration by means of partial fraction decomposition

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

I'm trying to solve this indefinite integral by means of partial fraction decomposition:

$\int\dfrac{x+1}{\left(x^2+4x+5\right)^2}\ dx$.

The denominator has complex (but not real) roots because $\Delta<0$; so, according with my calculus book, i try to decompose the integrand function in this form:

$\dfrac{x+1}{\left(x^2+4x+5\right)^2}=
\dfrac{Ax+B}{\left(x^2+4x+5\right)}+\dfrac{Cx+D}{\left(x^2+4x+5\right)^2}$.

I get:

$\dfrac{x+1}{\left(x^2+4x+5\right)^2}=
\dfrac{\left(Ax+B\right)\left(x^2+4x+5\right)+Cx+D}{\left(x^2+4x+5\right)^2}$.

Multiplying the right term:

$\dfrac{x+1}{\left(x^2+4x+5\right)^2}=
\dfrac{Ax^3+4Ax^2+5Ax+Bx^2+4Bx+5B+Cx+D}{\left(x^2+4x+5\right)^2}$.

Now i collect the terms with the same pwer of $x$:

$\dfrac{x+1}{\left(x^2+4x+5\right)^2}=
\dfrac{Ax^3+\left(4A+B\right)x^2+\left(5A+4B+C\right)x+D+ 5B}{\left(x^2+4x+5\right)^2}$.

Now i equate the two numerators:

$x+1=Ax^3+\left(4A+B\right)x^2+\left(5A+4B+C\right)x+D$

and equate term by term: i get:

$A=0$, $B=0$, $C=1$, $D=1$.

With these values i get a correct identity:

$\dfrac{x+1}{\left(x^2+4x+5\right)^2}=
\dfrac{x+1}{\left(x^2+4x+5\right)^2}$

but this is unuseful in order to solve the integral.

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: If partial fraction decomposition is not mandatory, choose $x+2=\tan y$

Comment: You are missing a $5B$ in the numerator. I inserted three stars $***$ for you. That is where the $5B$ has gone missing

Answer (score 4):

Here is an easy way
$$\int { \frac { x+1 }{ \left( x^{ 2 }+4x+5 \right) ^{ 2 } }  } dx=\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int { \frac { 2x+4-2 }{ \left( x^{ 2 }+4x+5 \right) ^{ 2 } }  } dx=\\ =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int { \frac { 2x+4 }{ \left( x^{ 2 }+4x+5 \right) ^{ 2 } } dx-\int { \frac { dx }{ \left( x^{ 2 }+4x+5 \right) ^{ 2 } }  }  } =\\ =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \underset { { I }_{ 1 } }{ \underbrace { \int { \frac { d\left( x^{ 2 }+4x+5 \right)  }{ \left( x^{ 2 }+4x+5 \right) ^{ 2 } }  }  }  } -\underset { { I }_{ 2 } }{ \underbrace { \int { \frac { d\left( x+2 \right)  }{ { \left( { \left( x+2 \right)  }^{ 2 }+1 \right)  }^{ 2 } }  }  }  } =$$
Obviously,$$\\ { I }_{ 1 }=-\frac { 1 }{ 2\left( x^{ 2 }+4x+5 \right)  } ,$$
now,let calculate ${ I }_{ 2 }$,substitute here $x+2=\tan { z } $,so that $${ I }_{ 2 }=\int { \frac { d\tan { z }  }{ { \left( { \tan ^{ 2 }{ z }  }+1 \right)  }^{ 2 } }  } =\int { \frac { \cos ^{ 4 }{ z }  }{ \cos ^{ 2 }{ z }  }  } dz=\int { \cos ^{ 2 }{ z } =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int { \left( 1+\cos { 2z }  \right
) dz }  } =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \left( z+\frac { \sin { 2z }  }{ 2 }  \right) $$
finally,

> $$\int { \frac { x+1 }{ \left( x^{ 2 }+4x+5 \right) ^{ 2 } }  } dx=\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \left( -\frac { 1 }{ \left( x^{ 2 }+4x+5 \right)  } -\arctan { \left( x+2 \right) -\frac { \sin { 2\left( \arctan { \left( x+2 \right)  }  \right)  }  }{ 2 }  }  \right) +C$$

Comment: much better then partial fractions $+1$

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comment directly use [Trigonometric substitution](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/integration/trigsub/trigsub.html)

As $x^2+4x+5=(x+2)^2+1^2,$ let $\arctan(x+2)=y\implies x+2=\tan y$

$$2I\int\dfrac{x+1}{(x^2+4x+5)^2}dx=\int(\tan y-1)\cos^2y\ dy$$

$$4I=2\int(\sin2y-1-\cos2y)dy=-\sin2y-2y-\cos2y+K$$

Now $\sin2y=\dfrac{2\tan y}{1+\tan^2y}=\cdots$

and $\cos2y=\dfrac{1-\tan^2y}{1+\tan^2y}=\dfrac2{1+\tan^2y}-1=\cdots$

Comment: I liked Battani's approach because I thought that he would avoid conventional wisdom, which is a trig sub. But then he used a trig sub nonetheless. Might as well go by your sledgehammer trig sub, which is probably what the majority of my students would do...+1

Answer (score 1):

Note that we can write the partial fraction expansion of $\frac{1}{(x+4x+5)^2}$ as

$$\frac{1}{(x+4x+5)^2}=\frac{1}{(x-r)^2(x-r^*)^2}=\frac{A}{x-r}+\frac{B}{(x-r)^2}+\frac{C}{x-r^*}+\frac{D}{(x-r^*)^2}$$

where $r=-2+i$ and $r^*=-2- i$.

Multiplying by $(x-r)^2$ and letting $x\to r$ reveals that $B=\frac{1}{(r-r^*)^2}=-\frac14$.

Multiplying by $(x-r)^2$, taking a derivative with respect to $x$, and letting $x\to r$ reveals that $A=-\frac{2}{(r-r^*)^3}=-\frac{i}{4}$.

Multiplying by $(x-r^*)^2$ and letting $x\to r^*$ reveals that $D=\frac{1}{(r^*-r)^2}=-\frac14$.

Multiplying by $(x-r^*)^2$, taking a derivative with respect to $x$, and letting $x\to r^*$ reveals that $C=\frac{2}{(r-r^*)^3}=\frac{i}{4}$.

---

Comment: $C=\frac{i}{4}$ Heelp:)

Comment: @imranfat I don't understand your comment.

Comment: MV Is the $C$ value really supposed to be complex?

Comment: @imranfat Yes, $A$ and $C$ are purely imaginary.

Comment: That means, that if we only consider real numbers, PFD cannot be performed? At least not according to http://www.quickmath.com/webMathematica3/quickmath/algebra/partialfractions/basic.jsp#c=partial_fractions_basicpartialfractions&v1=(x%2B1)%2F(x%5E2%2B4x%2B5)%5E2

Comment: @imranfat Clearly, the partial fraction expansion is correct.  The pairing of terms results in purely real functions.

Comment: I see it now, stupid denominator isn't factorable. I am such a doufus...

Comment: @imranfat No, you're not a "doufus" - at all.

Comment: Much appreciated. But since I realized that the denom is not factorable over the reals, completing the square would by my logical step. This is also the approach my students would learn from our calculus book. Ofcourse, one can go into complex factors and anti derive from there, but I am not sure if that is quicker. The answer from Lab is easier, in particular since, after completing the square, the constant is a perfect square (being $1$), so clearly a generic practice problem from a book...

Comment: Oh I see, it came in my inbox......